# Microservices user's access credentials

Tags: authorization, microservices

We are building a web application in microservices architecture.
We have a service that handles the authorization (i.e user's privileges, access credentials, roles etc...) and we are considering how to pass on these credentials in the system.

We have 2 option:
1. Sign those credentials in the gateway (auth and proxy service) using JWT and pass on all the information so every service could verify it (with its public key) and read the user's info.
2. Every service should make a request to the authorization service for querying the user's access on every action.

We are having difficulties on deciding which way is better in terms of high cohesion and loose coupling and of course making it easy for service development.

Answer (score 0):

You have some other options: instead of reinventing the wheel, you can use an OAuth 2.0 identity provider/broker out of the box.

Keycloak is a free open source identity provider and broker that provides all these functionalities.

Auth0 is a managed commercial service that provides all these functionalities too.

And I'm sure there are many other services exist for OAuth 2.0 protocol.

As for your 2 options:

You can extend the JWT with your custom authorisation claims (roles or permissions) and since the JWT will be signed, then it is safe to assume the data is correct by your service. Give that the JWT is a short lived token that need to renew every few minutes.

Comment: As for OAuth2.0, we are using OpenID connect authorization code flow in our organization, but each project has its own unique permissions system, so we do have to extend the provider JWT. As for the 2 options, I'm still looking for an answer where to verify the token, inside each service or in a central external service?

Comment: I think it is a good design that each service verify the token signature on its own. You can build a shared lib or dll which helps distribute this validation code to all your services.

Comment: There are plenty of libraries for doing this, in any language and platform, but I'm afraid doing this will cause coupling the service with the permission object model and design

Comment: Well. Authorisation is a cross-cutting concern in any layered or distributed system. Some code duplication and/or coupling will inevitably happen.